# Delphi: XML Node goes EInvalidPointer When I try to Access It

Tags: xml, delphi, firemonkey

I try to load a node only to face the EInvalidPointer error on Delphi.

My "xml" goes this way:

```
<RYCFile>
    <GeneralInfo>
        <SystemName/>
        <NSpecies>1</NSpecies>
        <NMaxCriterias>2</NMaxCriterias>
    <MaxRating>1</MaxRating>
        <SystemType>0</SystemType>
        <EvolutivePointCost>1</EvolutivePointCost>
    </GeneralInfo>
    <Race Index="1">
        <RaceName>Race #1</RaceName>
        <NumCriterias>2</NumCriterias>
        <Criteria Index="1">
            <Name>Criteria #1</Name>
                <NSubCriterias>0</NSubCriterias>
                <Limiter>0</Limiter>
            </Criteria>
            <Criteria Index="2">
                <Name>Criteria #2</Name>
                <NSubCriterias>0</NSubCriterias>
                <Limiter>0</Limiter>
            </Criteria>
        </Race>
</RYCFile>
```

I can't even read the DocumentElement.

I've googled everywhere but I'm at wit's end, it seems. Can't seem to find a solution remotely adapted to what I'm enduring.

Code used to "read":

```
FormSkeletonMaker.XMLDocumentFile.LoadFromFile(FileName);
FormSkeletonMaker.XMLDocumentFile.Active := True;
iNode := FormSkeletonMaker.XMLDocumentFile.ChildNodes.FindNode('GenInfo');
```

right now it goes this way. I'm barely testing the ability for this document to get loaded (it was made on the same program).

Comment: I updated the original post. Far more readable.

Comment: please use four spaces instead of "> " to format code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `DocumentElement` property fails, then either the `FormSkeletonMaker` or `XMLDocumentFile` object pointer is invalid.

Comment: The Form can't be the one behind it.
I chose to make XMLDocumentFile a component in my program (no dynamic loading or anything).
If anything, I try
Showmessage(XMLDocumentFile.XML.Text); and I get the whole xml.

Comment: It seems you're right. Somewhere the XMLDocumentFile went astray - I treated it like a dynamic one while it was static. Bad, bad error. 
The old code I tried out was using dynamic stuff and it didn't work simply because I had to create the xml document.

Comment: If you create a `TXMLDocument` dynamically without an `Owner` specified, it acts as a reference-counted interface (this is stated as much in the documentation), so you have to be extra careful of that.  Better to use the `NewXMLDocument()` and `LoadXML...()` functions instead, which return an `IXMLDocument` interface.